# Regular expression to remove the leading part of a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have different strings yet formatted the same with three words separated by whitespace. The goal is to delete the first part of the string. In other words, delete the leading data for each string.

What Perl regular expression will enable me to delete the leading data while keeping the rest of the string unaffected?

#### INPUT

```
String 1: Apples Peaches Grapes
String 2: Spinach Tomatoes Carrots
String 3: Corn Potatoes Rice
```

#### OUTPUT

```
String 1: Peaches Grapes
String 2: Tomatoes Carrots
String 3: Potatoes Rice
```

#### Perl

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

$string1 = "Apples Peaches Grapes";
$string2 = "Spinach Tomatoes Carrots";
$string3 = "Corn Potatoes Rice";

# Apply ReqExp to Delete the First Part of the String
$string1 =~ s/.../; 

say $string1;
say $string2;
say $string3;
```

Comment: try this `^.+?(?=\s)`     https://regex101.com/r/rnnul1/1

Comment: If your data doesn't really contain `String 1:` etc. then you shouldn't show it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string1 =~ s/^\S+\h+//;
```

- `^` beginning of string
- `\S+` 1 or more non space character
- `\h+` 1 or more horizontal spaces

If you're using a version of Perl older than v5.10, you may use:

```
$string1 =~ s/^\S+[ \t]+//;
```

Comment: Why don't use a simple `$str =~ s/^\S+\s+//` ?